# codeigniter search box and keeping data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I want to keep page in search form and when I visit another page and return to previous to see only what I search.

For example,  I have page with table, in that table I have list of all products which is 30 products. When I submit search query for some word and get per instance 5 products, I want to keep that and visit all another pages and when I back on product page to see again only that 5 products.

Any help?

Comment: check https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform

Comment: If you mean on set_value that doesn't exist because is erased when you left page. Table of my all products is in index(), but when I search something is in index/search

Comment: store value in seesion.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a way to store dynamic data. Your best bet would be to use something like [Sessions](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) or [LocalStorage](http://www.sitepoint.com/9-javascript-libraries-working-with-local-storage/)